WW2 sci-fi alien film from BBC
This is quite a tough one, as I believe this movie was made by the BBC, and so it would have been fairly lowish budget and not popular outside of the U.K.
All that I can remember about it is various details and scenes. 
It's a WW2 sci-fi alien film …
The scenes that I remember are a UFO flying alongside and overtaking a British spitfire plane, and another a scene where a UFO crash lands in WW2-era bombed out London. A typical London house, blown up, lots of rubble etc.
I believe that the alien may have had shape shifting abilities and there may have been a scene where it climbed out of the bombed out house/crash site/etc.
That's all that I can rememder from when I saw bits of the film many years ago.

Well the crashed spaceship in bombed out London would match with this opening scene from "Invasion: Earth".




I came across this in the 'Related Questions' sidebar.  I looked up 'Invasion: Earth' on Wikipedia (sorry, lack the skill to insert a link).  It was a 1998 6-part BBC TV series and from the synopsis, the first episode corresponds very closely to what's described.
